# Running a linux command to output to text file through PHP

Tags: php, linux

I was trying to get the following linux command to work using PHP. I read about the `shell_exec` command in PHP, that can be used to execute shell commands.

I am trying to output some simple text to a text file. I tried the following:

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'echo "hi" > Desktop/test/output.txt';
    shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Please note that, I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04. I have also made the www-data the owner of the Desktop/test folder so that it can write to it. The following is the command I used for that:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data Desktop/test
```

When I execute the above command, directly in a shell I can see an output.txt file created with the string output.

However, when I execute the php script through apache web server, I cannot see the output.txt file being created.

Glad if you can point me towards the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work, when you use an absolute path?

Comment: Try getting the output of the command to see if there is any error

Comment: try use absolute path: `/home/yourUserName/Desktop/test/output.txt`

Comment: You need to use absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment: you should use an absolute path.

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'echo "hi" > /home/username/Desktop/test/output.txt';
    shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a bit weird how the command worked without absolute path directly on the shell, but not through PHP.